# Caesar cipher : how to calculate with shifting value > 10 ( or larger )?

Tags: c++, ascii, caesar-cipher

As i know , the " formula " of Caesar Shifting is (x + k ) % 26 , where k is the shifting value and decryption just replace " + " to " - ".

but my code does not work when k > 10 (after i tested k = 10 , i find that the "shift" of the first few characters is wrong, so I estimate that k > 10 will be wrong (the number of incorrect characters increase) as well. ). I first change the characters to ASCII and then do the calculation. Finally change it back to characters.

Here are my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string target;
    char s;
    int k, i, num, length, j;
    cin >> s >> k;
    getline(cin, target);

    for (j = 0; j <= (int)target.length(); j++) {
        if ((target[j]) = ' ') {
            target.erase(j, 1);
        }
    }

    length = (int)target.length();

    if (s == 'e') {
        for (num = 0; num <= length; num++) {

            if (isupper(target[num]))
                target[num] = tolower(char(int(target[num] + k - 65) % 26 + 65));
            else if (islower(target[num]))
                target[num] = toupper(char(int(target[num] + k - 97) % 26 + 97));
        }
    }
    else if (s == 'd') {
        for (num = 0; num <= length; num++) {
            if (isupper(target[num]))
                target[num] = tolower(char(int(target[num] - k - 65) % 26 + 65));
            else if (islower(target[num]))
                target[num] = toupper(char(int(target[num] - k - 97) % 26 + 97));
            }
        }
    cout << target;
    return 0;
}
```

Let me put down the case which i failed to run.

input:

`d 10 n 3 V 3 D 3 N _ M Y N 3 _ S C _ N 3 L E`   ( input d / e first, then shifting value, finally the sequence of string require to " change ", the space is required to delete. )

the expected output:

`D3l3t3d_cod3_is_d3bu`

my output:

`D3l3:3d_cod3_i9_d3b;`
Thanks!

Comment: `A` and `a` make much more sense than `65` and `97`.

Comment: This is a very mysterious statement: "my code does not work when k > 10 ( I only tested k = 10 actually )".

Comment: sorry about that, after i tested k = 10 , i find that the "shift" of the first few characters is wrong, so I estimate that k > 10 will be wrong (the number of incorrect characters increase) as well.

Comment: I just edit the post, sorry for unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that when decoding you end up with negative numbers. With `k == 13` the expression `'T' - k - 65` gives `-7`. `-7 % 26` is still `-7`. `-7+65` is `58` which isn't a letter.

You can avoid negative numbers by simply setting k to `26 - k` when decoding.

Your code then simplifies to:

```
if (s == 'd') {
    k = 26 - k;
}
for (num = 0; num <= length; num++) {

    if (isupper(target[num]))
        target[num] = tolower(char(int(target[num] + k - 'A') % 26 + 'A'));
    else if (islower(target[num]))
        target[num] = toupper(char(int(target[num] + k - 'a') % 26 + 'a'));
}
```

Note I've replaced your integer constants with their equivalent characters which makes the code much easier to understand.
Note you also have a bug in your first loop `(target[j]) = ' '` should be `(target[j]) == ' '`.

Using all c++ has to offer you can reduce your code to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::string target = "mXLM";
    char s = 'e';
    int k = 7;

    target.erase(std::remove(target.begin(), target.end(), ' '), target.end());

    if (s == 'd') {
        k = 26 - k;
    }
    std::string result;
    std::transform(target.begin(), target.end(), std::back_inserter(result), [k](char in) {
        if (isalpha(in)) {
            char inputOffset = isupper(in) ? 'A' : 'a';
            char outputOffset = isupper(in) ? 'a' : 'A';
            return char(int(in + k - inputOffset) % 26 + outputOffset);
        }
        return in;
    });
    std::cout << result;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works ! but I am wondering why I use (target[j]) = ' ' can still get the output, what is the bug? Btw your reduced code is much more interesting haha!

Comment: I don't know, didn't work for me, just erased most of the string

Comment: As every other character of your input is a space the other bug in your loop of incrementing `j` after erasing works in your favour by unconditionally removing every other character.

Comment: I tried my sample case, same situation as you. Sorry about that ~ 
However, thanks for you explanation!